# Refactoring a nested foreach into Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists that I loop through to populate a final list, given that the inner loop satisfies a condition.

```
private List<Enum> getEnumFromType(List<Bean.Var> vars, List<Enum> enums) {
    List<Enum> enumList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Bean.Var var : vars) {
        String typeWithoutTypeIdentifierPrefix = var.getType().substring(1,var.getType().length());
        for (Enum enumVal : enums) {
            if (typeWithoutTypeIdentifierPrefix.equals(enumVal.getName())) {
                if (!enumList.contains(enumVal)) {
                    enumList.add(enumVal);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return enumList;
}
```

I have refactored the code to use the latest Java 8 streaming api and I came up with this:

```
vars.stream().forEach(
    var -> {
            String typeWithoutPrimitiveIdentifier = var.getType().substring(1,var.getType().length());

            enums.stream()
                    .filter(enumVal -> typeWithoutPrimitiveIdentifier(enumVal.getName()))
                    .forEach(enumVal -> {

                if (!enumList.contains(enumVal)) {
                    enumList.add(enumVal);
                }
        });
    }
);
```

How could I take this a step further to remove the nested foreach() methods?

Comment: ```.filter(enumVal -> typeWithoutPrimitiveIdentifier.equals(enumVal.getName()))```?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem by using `stream().forEach(..)` with a call to `add` inside the `forEach` (so you mutate the external `enumList` instance) is that you can run easily into concurrency issues if someone turns the stream in parallel and the collection is not thread safe.

Instead you should favor the collect approach which is suited for mutable reductions:

```
private Set<Enum> getEnumFromType(List<Bean.Var> vars, List<Enum> enums) {
    return vars.stream()
               .map(var -> var.getType().substring(1))
               .map(v -> enums.stream().filter(e -> v.equals(e.getName())).findAny())
               .filter(Optional::isPresent)
               .map(Optional::get)
               .collect(toSet());
}
```

You may also want to build the mappings `String -> Enum` upfront to avoid multiple filtering.

```
private Set<Enum> getEnumFromType(List<Bean.Var> vars, List<Enum> enums) {
    Map<String, Enum> enumsName = enums.stream().collect(toMap(Enum::getName, e -> e, (e1, e2) -> e1));
    return vars.stream()
               .map(var -> var.getType().substring(1))
               .map(enumsName::get)
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .collect(toSet());
}
```

If you really want to return a `List`, you can look at `Collectors.collectingAndThen`.

Comment: *If you really want to return a List, you can look at Collectors.collectingAndThen* or use `.distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 2):

I would split this into two operations:

1. Get a list of types without the primitive identifier.
2. Finding all of the `Enum`s whose name is one of them, collecting them into a `Set` to ensure there are no duplicates.

Here's what I came up with, but it's untested:

```
private List<Enum> getEnumFromType(List<Bean.Var> vars, List<Enum> enums) {
    List<String> typesWithoutPrefix = vars.stream()
        .map(e -> e.getType().substring(1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Set<Enum> set = enums.stream()
        .filter(e -> typesWithoutPrefix.contains(e.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return new ArrayList<>(set);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
private List<Enum> getEnumFromType(List<Bean.Var> vars, List<Enum> enums) {
    return new ArrayList<>(
        vars.stream()
            .map(var -> var.getType().substring(1))
            .flatMap(s -> enums.stream()
                .filter(e -> s.equals(e.getName())))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    );
}
```

The order of return value will be different from yours.