# Refactoring nested for loop into Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following for loop:

```
    List<Map> mapList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Resource resource : getResources()) {
        for (Method method : resource.getMethods()) {
            mapList.add(getMap(resource,method));
        }
    }
    return mapList;
```

How could I refactor this nested loop into a Java 8 stream?

Comment: You asked a similar question "Refactoring a nested foreach into Java 8 stream" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406744/refactoring-a-nested-foreach-into-java-8-stream/34406832. Didn't you learn something from that?

Comment: No, I am still trying to get my head around it

Comment: Then it seems you have tried something, I suggest that you post your attempt. Sometimes it helps someone answering to explain why your approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to obtain all the `Map`s for all `Method`s of all `Resource`s :

```
List<Map> mapList = 
    getResources().stream()
                  .flatMap(r->r.getMethods().stream().map(m->getMap(r,m)))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: To me, the version with stream looks far more unreadable compared to one with loops (in this particular case)

Comment: @WandMaker In that case, you should definitely stick with loops.