# Change two foreach to one stream

Tags: java, for-loop, java-stream

Somebody have maybe any idea how can I replace this with `stream()`?

```
for (Customer customer : customers) {
    if (customer.getProducts() != null && customer.getProducts().getProduct() != null) {
        for (Product product : customer.getProducts().getProduct()) {
            if (product.getId().equals(productId)) {
                return Optional.of(product);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know, that second foreach I can replace with:

```
customer.getProducts().getProduct().stream().filter(a -> a.getId().equals(productId)).findAny();
```

But how can I replace both foreachs with one stream?

Comment: Look into flatMap()

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406744/refactoring-a-nested-foreach-into-java-8-stream)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flatMap` to get a `Stream` of all `Product`s of all `Customer`s.

```
Optional<Product> product =
    customers.stream()
             .filter(c -> c.getProducts() != null && c.getProducts().getProduct() != null)
             .flatMap(c -> c.getProducts().getProduct().stream())
             .filter(p -> p.getId().equals(productId))
             .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the answer from @Eran already is correct, I prefer the below more. The only difference is to have only one operation per line (with the cost of having finally more lines), which is in *my* eyes cleaner:

```
Optional<Product> product = customers.stream()     // Stream<Customer>
         .map(Customer::getProducts)               // Stream<Products>
         .filter(Objects::nonNull)                 // filter null values out
         .map(Products::getProduct)                // Stream<Collection<Product>>
         .filter(Objects::nonNull)                 // filter null values out
         .flatMap(Collection::stream)              // Stream<Product>
         .filter(p -> p.getId().equals(productId)) // filter product with id out
         .findAny();                               // Optional<Product>
```