# Is it possible to perform this operation in just one line?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Assuming that the list firstName has already been initialized.

```java
List<String> firstName= new ArrayList<String>();
firstName.add("John");
firstName.add("Peter");
firstName.add("Foo");
```

Is it possible to use it to fill another list in just one line of code? I don not know how to do it in less lines than the following:

```java
List<FullName> fullName= new ArrayList<FullName>();
firstName.stream().forEach( n -> fullName.add(new FullName(n, "SomeSurname")));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can easily be done by using `map` instead of `forEach` to create `FullName`s, then `Collectors.toList` to create the list.

```
firstName.stream().map(n -> new FullName(n, "SomeSurname")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Not only is it one statement, it's [preferable to do it this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406744/refactoring-a-nested-foreach-into-java-8-stream?rq=1), if there's a possibility of parallel streams, to avoid concurrency issues.  Additionally, it's not desired to use `forEach`, typically used for side effects, as the main purpose, which here is collecting to a list.

Also, you shouldn't worry about it being only one line.  Readability is more important than being stingy on the number of lines.  It has been made into one statement, even if it's multiple lines.  Typically each operation on a Java stream is separated on to its own line.

```
firstName.stream()
    .map(n -> new FullName(n, "SomeSurname"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you wanted, you could even combine the creation of the initial list into a single statement.

```
List<FullName> fullName = Arrays.asList("John", "Peter", "Foo").stream()
    .map(n -> new FullName(n, "SomeSurname"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```